# Limiting memory access

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, instructions

How do we really limit machine memory access if a software code has a instruction that work with straight address bits and order cpu to access access a restricted area?

if we use container or virtual or ..., we should run a code to check every instruction of original code to see if it doesn't access a restricted area?

Answer (score 0):

Privilege management usually requires hardware support in the CPU. In the case of software emulation, the emulator will be required to ensure the proper privilege levels are enforced.

The [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) is a component that (among other things) controls memory accesses. Certain regions of memory can be marked as readable, writable and executable. The MMU will check all memory accesses and cause some sort of fault on an illegal access. This prevents the CPU from reading/writing/executing at arbitrary memory locations.

Many CPUs have privilege separation built into the CPU itself. It will have a concept of privilege levels (e.g. rings in x86, mode bits in ARM) and checks that the instruction being run is allowed within the current privilege level. This prevents code running in an unprivileged mode from executing privileged instructions.

The operating system hosting the containers or virtual machine host software will need to ensure the proper privilege separation is implemented correctly (making use of hardware features as appropriate).

Comment: Wow thanks, i thought about it but i think its very complex in hardware! And very resource intensive in software to run an inst for every instr! Not just vm, any ins in host also!